# user private photos system using mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site where users can request to see other users private photos. The whole system is set up using php and mysql.

The basic idea is that one user can request to see another's private photo collection. by default every user in the database is set to and enum value of 'o' and if they send a request to see pictures and the user accepts this their enum value changes to 1 and they can see the users private photos.

I have this working fine, however i have created a table called 'permissions' with three columns like so:

```
user_id     |     private_id     |   privilege 
   2                  4                  1
   5                  6                  0
```

so by demonstration from the table above; user id 2 can now see user id 4's private pictures.
However user id 5 can not see user id 6's photos.

Like i said the basic idea works but at the moment if a user doesn't have permission or an enum value of 1 then they're suppose to see template image(s) with a padlock.

At the moment only the users which are paired in this table can view the padlock images/template images.

so for instance if user_id = 2 and private_id = 1 - then user 2 will be able to see the padlock/template images.

But this is wrong because i want all users to be able to see the padlock images (when logged in) if they have an enum value of 0.

Can someone show me where i am going wrong? I have tried but i can't figure it out. thanks.

i think i should also mention that i have a table called 'users' which holds my main user_ids, with email, contact numbers etc, and the table 'permissions' user_id has just been setup as an additional table to manage the permissions, so this might need to = 'users.user_id' but I'm not too sure of this, because i am still learning mysql.

FUNCTION:

```
function account_perms() {
            global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
            global $profile_id;
            $query = "SELECT ptb_permissions.user_id, ptb_permissions.private_id, ptb_permissions.privellages
                        FROM ptb_permissions
                        WHERE ptb_permissions.private_id = \"$profile_id\"
                        AND ptb_permissions.user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id']." ";
            $account_perms = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($query, $connection);
            return $account_perms;
        }
```

CODE:

```
    <div="tj_gallery">
<? if (logged_in()) { ?>
<?php include('includes/mod_profile/mod_photos/private.php'); ?>
<? } ?>  
</div>
```

PRIVATE.PHP:

```
           <?php            
$photo = "data/private_photos/$profile[1]/pic1.jpg";
if (!file_exists($photo)) {
    $photo = "data/photos/0/_default.jpg";
}
$thumb = "data/private_photos/$profile[1]/thumb_pic1.jpg";
if (!file_exists($thumb)) {
    $thumb = "data/photos/0/_default.jpg";
}
 if (logged_in()) {
echo
"<li><a href=\"$photo\" rel=\"shadowbox\" title=\"<strong>$profile[2]'s Photo's</strong>\"><img src=\"$thumb\" width=\"90\" height=\"90\" alt=\"<strong>{$profile[2]}'s Photos</strong>\"  /></a></li>";

}
?>

<? } } ?>

<?

$account_perms = account_perms();

        while ($perms = mysql_fetch_array($account_perms)) {
             if ($perms['privellages'] == '0')  {


$photo = "data/private_photos/0/_default.jpg";
if (!file_exists($photo)) {
    $photo = "data/photos/0/_default.jpg";
}
$thumb = "data/private_photos/0/_default.jpg";
if (!file_exists($thumb)) {
    $thumb = "data/photos/0/_default.jpg";
}
 if (logged_in()) {
echo
"<li><a href=\"privileges.php\" rel=\"shadowbox;height=300;width=500\" title=\"<strong>Access Denied</strong>\"><img src=\"$thumb\" width=\"90\" height=\"90\" alt=\"<strong>{$profile[2]}'s Photos</strong>\"  /></a></li>";

 } 


?>


            <? } } ?>
```

Comment: *(related)* [Global in Functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions)

Comment: Please try to make your code a bit more readable by following indentation guidelines, this will make it easier for someone to help.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to have an entry in the table for a default state. It would probably be easier to only add an entry if someone has received permission (you could always log denied requests elsewhere or in the same table using your status flag if you need those).

Now look for a record with the combination of user and collection, if such a record exists the user has permission and is shown the photos. Otherwise go the default state and show the access denied page.

This way you avoid your current problem which is simply that you do not have an entry for people who have not asked permission (and thus not denied or approved) and you get an unhandled case: no padlock images showing up.